# Looping through the ol tag in preg_replace() function

Tags: php

I am trying to replace new lines of a code with html ol tag to display the code as

```
1. Line 1
2. Line 2
3. Line 3
4. Line 4
```

Here is my php

```
$x="Line 1
      Line 2
      Line 3
      Line 4";

 echo preg_replace("/\n+([^\n]+)/","<ol start='1'><li>$1</li></ol>",$x);
```

The problem is ol tag is not looping in the preg_replace() function,so It outputs

```
1. Line 1
1. Line 2
1. Line 3
1. Line 4
```

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating multiply `ol` tags instead of wrapping the `ol` around the `preg_replace` function. You can also simplify your regex with the [`m` modifier](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

```
$x="Line 1 
      Line 2 
      Line 3 
      Line 4";

echo "<ol start='1'>" . preg_replace("/^(.*?)$/m", "<li>$1</li>", $x) . "</ol>";
```

Alternative if you don't want the trailing newlines simply use:

```
/^(.*?)\s?$/m
```

> When this modifier is set, the "start of line" and "end of line" constructs match immediately following or immediately before any newline in the subject string, respectively, as well as at the very start and end. This is equivalent to Perl's /m modifier.

Source: [php.net](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but ol tag is still not looping. 1 1 1 1, but I want 1 2 3 4 as new lines

Answer (score 1):

Keep outside the replace `<ol start='1'>` as it must be only once in the resulting html

```
echo "<ol start='1'>".preg_replace("/\n+([^\n]+)/","<li>$1</li>",$x)."</ol>";
```